# I did not manually acknowledge a message, then rabbitmq give it again after 1min, can i extend this time？

Tags: python, rabbitmq

In my python3 code. When i get the a message, first i need to do a long-time job. So i want to acknowledge the message when the job done. But if i dont acknowledge the message right now, it will consume the same message after 1min. So, i want to know can i set this time longer?

my code:

```
def do_work(body, tag):
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), 'I get body:', body, tag)
    # simulate a long time job
    time.sleep(70)
    # ack the message
    channel.basic_ack(tag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for method, properties, body in channel.consume('dolphin'):
    t = Thread(target=do_work, args=(body, method.delivery_tag))
    t.start()

""" console output:
2019-04-16 17:32:02.200645 I get body: b'2019-04-16 17:31:31.440033' 1
2019-04-16 17:33:05.879708 I get body: b'2019-04-16 17:31:31.440033' 2
2019-04-16 17:34:10.885120 I get body: b'2019-04-16 17:31:31.440033' 3
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a question, you **must** provide the name and version of all software you are using. In this case, what version of RabbitMQ, Erlang, Python and what Python library you are using.

> But if i dont acknowledge the message right now, it will consume the
> same message after 1min.

This is probably because your `sleep` call blocks heartbeat messages and RabbitMQ thinks your client application has died. RabbitMQ will close the connection and re-enqueue the message.

If you are using the Pika library, your code is not correct. You can't acknowledge a message from another thread.

Please see [this example code](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/1.0.1/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py) for how to correctly acknowledge a message from another thread.

Comment: Thank you so much. I use the amqp service of aliyun, so I dont know the version of rabbitmq, I use python3.6 and pika 0.11.2.

Comment: Then i just ask help from aliyun, they tell me when a message have not ack, then it will re-enqueue the message. To my surprise, I install a RabbitMQ 3.5.7, Erlang 18.3 in a ubuntu16.04 computer, then I find that the re-enqueue message didnt happen! So, maybe I should ask aliyun to cancel their re-enqueue strategy or just add some arguement to my code?